# WSO2 admin UI "Try it" breaks when XSLT 2.0 is enabled in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

As per following URL I enabled the XSLT 2.0 support

[Achala Blog Entry](http://achala11.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-get-xslt-20-support-with-wso2.html)

how ever it looks like the TryIt service is not working after that. When in Admin UI I click on "Try This Service" link I get following error

```
[2012-09-10 11:47:03,491]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin' logged in at [2012-09-10 11:47:03,0491] from IP address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0
Warning: at xsl:stylesheet on line 32 of :
  Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor
Warning: on line 286 of :
  The attribute axis starting at a namespace() node will never select anything
Error on line 1603 of :
  XPTY0004: Required item type of second operand of '|' is node(); supplied value has item
  type xs:string
[2012-09-10 11:47:09,515] ERROR - Util Required item type of second operand of '|' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string
; SystemID: ; Line#: 1603; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError: Required item type of second operand of '|' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string
```

When I undo what is mentioned in the blog entry to bring back XSLT 1.0 support this error goes away. Can you please help.
thanks
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the TryIt component is bound to XSLT 1.0 syntax, and uses Salan. So if you use remove Salan and add saxson, the try-it fill break. This issue is rectified in the new ESB (4.5.0).

Regards,
/Nuwan